# Vuetify 3: How to define button font size based on button size?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have created settings.scss, and I have achieved to set button size with this

```
$typography: ('button': ('size': 14px))
```

and with this

```
$button-font-size: 14px,
```

But what should I do to have font size different for different button sizes?

PS. In Vuetify 2 I have used this

```
$btn-font-sizes: (
  'small': 13px,
  'large': 14px,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The SASS now uses a [relative scaling function](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3122b69b3bad6fa40cf56ff898ff1fbc3ce459b5/packages/vuetify/src/components/VBtn/_mixins.scss#L8) for button `height`, `font-size`, `width-ratio`, `padding-ratio` based off the default [button size settings](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3122b69b3bad6fa40cf56ff898ff1fbc3ce459b5/packages/vuetify/src/components/VBtn/_variables.scss#L68). With this setup you can can achieve a relative scaling of button size related CSS props using `settings.$size-scales`:

*In your [settings.scss](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#component-specific-variables):*

```
@forward 'vuetify/settings' with (
  $size-scales: (
    'x-small': -0.7,
    'small': -0.2,
    'default': 0,
    'large': 2,
    'x-large': 10
  )
);
```

The advantage to this approach is convenience, and that you can easily add custom sizes like `xx-small` or whatever. However, if you only want to change font-size and not other properties you have to target each button size in CSS:

```
.v-btn--size-x-small {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

Of course, you can use the class names to target any property of buttons and avoid the settings altogether.